# Connecting to existing Heroku Postgres DB for Sinatra app

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku, salesforce, sinatra-activerecord

I am using Salesforce for my CRM, but need to query data (multiple records, so no Zapier) for a Heroku based Sinatra app. Heroku provides a service that replicates Salesforce objects to Postgres tables regularly which gets my data out of Salesforce.

I've coded a Sinatra app before and hosted it on Heroku so I'm a bit familiar with the process of setting up a dev db locally then pushing it to production via the many tutorials. However, i'm running into an issue finding any information that will allow me to connect to the existing production Postgres DB that already is populated with the data I need while having no need to create and connect to a local dev db.

Heroku provides me with the following
[image]

How and where to I plug in these various credentials securely so my following files have the right information to connect to tables Venue__c and Spaces__c?
app.rb
/config
- database.yml
- environments.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Heroku has a great tutorial that not only connects to the replicated database, but is also written for Sinatra.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-heroku-and-connect-without-local-dev#introduction

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have `ActiveRecord`, it should just be a case of configuring your `database.yml` correctly. For example, to directly connect your development environment, use something like:

```
# database.yml
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: your_database
  username: your_user
  password: your_password
  host: your_host
  port: your_port

# or alternatively, using the URI
development:
  url: postgres://your_user:your_password@your_host/your_database
```

Comment: Is it a necessity to create a development db? Is your solution suggesting I can use the live Heroku Postgres db as my development db? I am using ActiveRecord, but I have not run any rakes, is that something I need to do considering this db automatically had data pushed to it on a regular basis?

Comment: @csakon: yes, this would connect directly to the DB on Heroku. If you need a dev database there are a few options. You could set up a secondary Salesforce account and set up a new Postgres DB for it to sync with, and develop on top of that. Or if you don't care about sync then you can set up a local Postgres DB and import your data from live to dev (see here for more details: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#restore-to-local-database)

Comment: I don't care about having a dev db environment really (your code should maybe say 'production:'? But more importantly, the issue i'm having is the connection, I already had the code you provided above, but it's just not connecting (Internal Server Error). I'm wondering if there is something different I do if i'm connecting to an existing db with existing data vs setting one up from scratch.

Comment: `development` was intentional here, to allow your dev server to connect to the DB; but you could certainly use `production` too if you run your server in production mode. I would recommend running locally in dev mode and then posting up the logs - it should give you a much more informative error than "internal server error"

Comment: I'm getting an ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError at /ra054100000DMnRF/chad/stinson
FATAL: role "your_username" does not exist which you can see here: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s2/sh/b36d645d-3f86-4f8c-af01-1f019d97c9ea/cd3e81c12ebff030c46ad781b57197e6

Comment: `database.yml` is a file used in rails to configure your database as explained in the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24321632/where-does-database-yml-get-loaded-in-activerecord-in-rails-4). As you can see rails 4 will even fall back to the `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` environment variable if it is not present. In Sinatra you have to use `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(...)` yourself as explained in [this blogpost](https://samuelstern.wordpress.com/2012/11/28/making-a-simple-database-driven-website-with-sinatra-and-heroku/). It should guide you properly.

Comment: @csakon: does it work if you use your _production DB_ config values in the _development section_ of `database.yml`? The error is saying that there is no role called "your_username" for the database you're trying to connect to

Answer (score 0):

Heroku publishes your database credentials to you through a URL in an environment variable. You should be able to access it through `ENV.fetch("DATABASE_URL")`. Depending on your ORM you will use different ways to connect to your database, e.g. `Sequel` is able to use this value directly as a parameter to `Sequel.connect(ENV.fetch("DATABASE_URL"))`.

As you seem to use `ActiveRecord` you could be using `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(...)` as suggested in [this post](http://mherman.org/blog/2013/06/08/designing-with-class-sinatra-plus-postgresql-plus-heroku/#.WNr4LRj5wxM) which also exemplifies how to parse the URL (which might not be necessary anymore). This does not translate directly to a `database.yml`, but since you do not plan to use Rails you will have to provide your own version of `environment.rb` or some such and it should be easy enough to do in that place.